# Chaining Connections

Tags: challenge

The LEGO [2x4 brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3001#T=C) is somewhat of an icon of LEGO, and the majority of official LEGO bricks can connect back to it. However, the number of bridging bricks required can vary, depending on the piece. Some pieces, like a [1x1 Round Tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138#T=C), can be connected directly to it; however, others, like the [Technic Axle 32](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50450#T=C), require additional pieces (in this case, the [Technic Brick 1 x 2 with Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32064)) to bridge the gap.

The piece I can think of that requires the most of said bridging pieces to connect back to a 2x4 is the body of the [Bohrok Canister assembly](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=42718c01#T=C), which requires 4 pieces to reach the 2x4: the lid, the hanger clip, a [Bohrok ribcage](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41665#T=C), and a [1x2 Brick With Pin](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2458#T=C). My challenge is, can you do me one better? What piece takes the most bridging pieces to connect back to a standard 2x4, and what is the chain required for it?

Rules:

- The piece must be official LEGO; no messing around with off-brand pieces with absurd new connection types.
- All connections used must be legal; no strapping things together with rubber bands and calling it good (that would take all the fun out of it).
- There must actually be a method of connecting the pieces together; pieces like the [ball](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41250#T=C) used in [Scorpion Palace](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7418-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) or any of the BIONICLE canisters without built-in studs are just cheating.

Comment: This might actually be a good puzzle for Puzzling.SE, but you already posted it here, so.

Comment: I feel like puzzling is more about wordplay or math tricks than physical stuff.

Comment: This is a nice break from the usual "what is this obscure part" -- no problem with this IMHO.

Comment: I suggest that you post your best solution as a separate answer (possibly with pictures), so it can be separately commented and voted upon.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Sadly, I no longer have any of the original Bohrok canisters. However, physical construction of the winning chain isn't necessarily a requirement; this is more a parts knowledge test than a supply one.

Answer (score 6):

*This answer is based upon the **wrong** assumption that [Technic chain links and conveyor-belt links (a.k.a. bulldozer chain links)](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=9852-1) connect to nothing except each other.
As remarked by [Ivan Sanchez](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7970/chaining-connections/8200?noredirect=1#comment15519_8200), this is contradicted by [this set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=40175-1), which uses a connection between a conveyor-belt link and a [standard arm/rod](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88072).*

Assuming that these chain links only connect to each other, the only way to connect them to something else, is wrapping eight of them around a standard [16-cog gear](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4019). (You can also wrap six of them around an [8-cog gear](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3647), but I would not consider that a robust and intended connection.)

Finally, the gear can be connected to a [length-3 axle with stud](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6587), which in turn can be connected to the bottom of the 2×4 brick.

For bulldozer chain links, this looks like this:

[image: Parts]

[image: Construction]

Now, it depends on how you interpret the challenge: You need **nine** other pieces to connect the chain link to the 2×4 brick. However, many of those pieces are again chain links and there are only **two** pieces between every chain link and the 2×4 brick.

Comment: I'm terribly tempted to give it to you... I'm just trying to figure out whether connecting those links to standard rods is legal. If it is, a [1x4 antenna](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3957#T=C) drops the chain down to one link.

Comment: I think you can also actually clip them to one of the various thin antenna pieces like [2569](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=153), although I would assume that's not a "legal" connection.

Comment: Couldn't you use a [88072 Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Arm Up](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88072&idColor=11) to connect the thread to the brick? I think [40175-1 Policeman with Cookie and Stinger polybag](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=40175-1) is using that technique.

Comment: @IvanSanchez: That’s what Lepidolite Mica suggested in the first comment, leaving the question whether it was a legal connection, which the set you reference answers. See my edit. (At least that set is younger than my answer.)

Answer (score 4):

#### Thornax, 7 connections.

This is just a start, but here's a 2x4 connection to a BIONICLE thornax.

[image]

#### BIONICLE Ball, 6 connections

The extra two pieces are needed to hold the ball in place, making it truly connected.

[image]

Comment: Ooh. Sorry, but [this brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85943) and a [4 axle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3705#T=C) can bring the Thornax down to a 4-piece chain, and it can be used with the Zamor sphere as well. You're on the right track, though!

Comment: You could also get it down to 3 pieces by putting a stud in the Thornax launcher's pin hole (maybe not technically legal anymore, but I know LEGO has done it before).

Answer (score 4):

I have another case for 4 connections.
[18592](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18592#T=C) - Propeller 3 Blade 13 Diameter (Ninjago Airjitzu Flyer Vortex Rotor), can be attached to 2 x 4 brick with a help of following 3 parts below:

- [18590](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18590#T=C&C=11) - Technic, Gear 8 Tooth with Pin Holes and Ninjago
  Flywheel Socket - Short Shaft
- [18585](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18585#T=C&C=11) - Brick, Modified 2 x 4 with Pin Holes and
  Flywheel Socket (Ninjago Airjitzu Flyer Handle)
- [16965](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=16965#T=C) - Human
  Tool, Rip Cord Flexible with Handle Thick for Ninjago Airjitzu Flyers

Comment: I could do it with 2 pieces, [6558 Pin 3L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6558) and [2444 Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Pin Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2444). Or maybe even 1 [15461 piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15461) if putting a stud in the pin hole is allowed.

Comment: None of these parts provide a connection and I would consider them cheating similar to using gravity to call it "zero piece solution", rubber bands or string with studs on both ends to call it "single piece solution".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to list the black circular piece that connects to the propeller. Those pieces would connect to that piece and hold the propeller in place. I've done something similar to attach it to an axel before.

Comment: In any case, my suggestions probably aren't 'legal' so this isn't a bad answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution is targeted to be applied on top of 18590 piece, where Trans-Clear cone is used to be attached in a set. I cannot see how such solution could be applied from the bottom of the propeller. Or am i missing something? In such case propeller would only hold if notches within propeller wouldn't align with cuts on 18590 part. Otherwise the propeller would fall off. So a bit of grey area here, as luck is now involved here.

Comment: Sort-of, although after some testing, it's still possible to spin the propeller and detach it... [I found little bit different way to do it in 3 pieces though](https://i.imgur.com/8WLhzRx.jpg). And [a really goofy piece which can do it in 2](https://i.imgur.com/WmRwLfW.jpg) ([this piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4318) which has been attached to a Technic pin hole in [Polar Base](https://brickset.com/sets/6575-1/Polar-Base)).

Answer (score 3):

Are you counting sub-assemblies as separate pieces?

How about part [983](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=1761) a Minifigure hand.

That requires 981 Arm, 973 Torso, 970 Hips, and 971 a Leg.

For a minimum total of **four interconnections**.

Comment: ...you really don't need any connecting pieces to attach a minifig hand to a brick...

Comment: Minifigure hand can have any piece with 3.18 mm bar attached. You can then use any part which has both 3.18 mm bar and stud (or anti stud) to get hand attached to 2 x 4 brick. For example, Bar 1L with 1 x 1 Round Plate with Hollow Stud (32828) can be attached in two ways (with stud and anti-stud). This would bring it to just two connections.

Comment: Actually, ignore my suggestion above. Minifigure hand has a stud itself! This means it can be attached directly to 2 x 4 brick's anti-stud on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of the LEGO storage systems (https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/lego-8-stud-black-storage-brick-drawer-5005718) or apparel could be a candidate?